# How to use WordPress header function and footer function and not load word press database

Tags: plugins, php, database

I am no longer able to access my database after including WordPress functions in my index.php file.

I used the following WordPress functions to access the WordPress header and footer

```
<?php
    @require '../wp-load.php';
    get_header(); 
    get_footer();
```

I need to use the WordPress header and footer and also use my external database without conflicting with each other.

**ISSUE**

I properly access the WordPress header and footer but now my EXTERNAL database is no longer accessible

Kindly help

Comment: How are you trying to access your external database? Keep in mind that if you’re loading WordPress then you can’t use any functions, classes or global variables with the same names as anything in WordPress.

Comment: If you’re trying to display content from outside Wordpress inside the same template/design as your WordPress site a much better approach would be to create a plug-in that integrates with WordPress.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the is away to do that.

Comment: Why is there a `@` in your require statement? You should never load `wp-load.php` like that, it's fragile and prone to problems, such as the one you're facing now. Note that you can access non-WP databases inside WP, either by using a new instance of `wpdb` or calling the APIs directly.

Comment: @TomJNowell How do I use new instance of `wpdb`?

Comment: If you still need help with this it would be a good idea to also add the code where you're accessing your database outside of WP